# Spring 3: @ResponseBody - How to control the response to get the XML or JSON?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-3

I'm using `<mvc:annotation-driven />` Spring (3.0) configuration (without [ContentNegotiatingViewResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.html)). According to the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-annotation-driven) Spring 3 supports JSON and XML. Using `@ResponseBody` on handler method like below gives JSON response. How to control the response to get the XML or JSON ?

```
@RequestMapping("/data")
public @ResponseBody User getUser() {
    return new User();
}
```

**EDIT**

Used Maven dependencies:

```
<!-- xml -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.8</version>
</dependency>

<!-- json --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Debugging [AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.html) => jaxb2Present = true, jacksonPresent = true

Comment: You would have to specify that in the request

Comment: Take a look at mvc-ajax samples from Spring SVN https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/mvc-ajax/trunk/

Comment: @Random I found nothing usable :(

Comment: http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/ ?

Comment: @Random Thanks for a link. I came across this article several times, but unfortunately does not give an answer to my question, it relates to Ajax/JSON - that works for me. I need help to get XML response. I need only (or perhaps too much) that `http://server/.../json` return JSON, and `http://server/.../data` return XML, using Spring 3 annotations.

Comment: @marioosh - BTW are you Polish? :) Try look around for RESTFull implementation samples, you may find how to render to different formats. http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/

Answer (score 4):

Spring uses the "Accept" header of the request to decide whether to send JSON or XML. If both are accepted, then you you'll get one or the other, I can't remember gets checked first.

To get an XML, your client needs to have "application/xml" in the header, rather than "application/json ".

Answer (score 0):

Use `@ResponseBody` like this. Method below takes JSON as request parameter and returns JSON response.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "...", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public Object RestPOSTService(@RequestBody JsonContent content,
        HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        .....
    return (JSON);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's configured in RequestMapping

```
@RequestMapping(
 value = "...", 
 method = {RequestMethod.POST},produces ="application/json")
 public @ResponseBody Object getObject() { ... }
```